# Inkscape - Text gets clipped around end

Tags: vector, inkscape, icon

I've been using Inkscape to design some prototype icons for a project I'm working on, and recently I ran into an issue with the battery design. The issue is my text for the battery gets clipped around the end. I haven't ran into this issue on any other text objects. Here's the image:

[image: Battery icon]

This isn't much of an issue but since I'll be using this in the actual project that I'm working on it is going to be an issue if it happens when I make the final icon. The font is Helvetica Neue if that helps. (And I'm using Partha's Inkscape build (Inkscape 0.91))

Original SVG: https://www.sendspace.com/file/cm5wpt

Comment: At first sight it seems that the text is partially hidden by a white rectangle or by a white blur surrounding the battery. Is the text at the top level of the stack?

Comment: @Paolo: I guess the text is added dynamically and not part of the image.

Comment: @joyesh: Did you export your image by selecting the image, or did you do a selection, and export that, or did you export the page and has the image a border to the page border? Or is your image used as SVG and this is a screenshot? Am I right, that the text is dynamically added by the program?

Comment: If the text is dynamically added, it should be moved on an upper level on the application or on the web page.

Comment: @PaoloGibellini I added the text on the highest layer, but even that didn't work

Comment: @userunknown No, I exported the full page (which was set at the size of the icon)

Comment: I see. Can you post the original SVG file?

Comment: @PaoloGibellini Will edit the post and put the SVG.

Answer (score 3):

Your text is nested in a lot of groups, one of which is used by a [clip path](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Clip.html) and is the cause of the truncation of the text. You can see it in the XML Editor:

[image: xml]

The fastest way to free your text is select it and keep hit **Shift-Ctrl-G** to [ungroup](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/basic/tutorial-basic.html) until your text is no more grouped:

[image: Ungrouped text]

Alternatively, you can change the size of the clipping rectangle.